# How to add background image to HTML5 canvas sketchpad?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, html5-canvas

I use the Responsive Sketchpad - [demo](https://theisensanders.com/responsive-sketchpad/) and [Github](https://github.com/tsand/responsive-sketchpad). What is the proper way to set the background image (instead of white background) which will fully responsive with that HTML5 canvas sketchpad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.canvas{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(https://s.ill.in.ua/i/news/630x373/397/397742.jpg);
}
```

worked fine for me
[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you. I have just one thing. How can I set the height of that canvas box and keep background image responsive. For example how align the height of canvas box (with background image) to the height of right box in demo?

Comment: in demo you can see that both canvas and right box have width set in percents [link](http://prntscr.com/omhiqb) classes `two-thirds` and `one-third`, so you can play with those values to achieve what you want. Please set this answer as accepted if it answered your initial question.

Comment: Unfortunately I am able to change width in these classes but as I wrote before I can't  change **height** of canvas box.